# gunicorn - django - boto -serve static files via S3 - how to set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as environment variables

Tags: django, deployment, amazon-s3, gunicorn

I m using s3 to story my static files and [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) to serve them.

```
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
    STATIC_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

I tried to deploy my app on heroku and in order to authenticate my process to access S3 one can set the access credentials as such:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key ID>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<key>
```

This worked on heroku.

I tried the same approach for webfaction, but always get the following error:

```
NoAuthHandlerFound at /admin/
No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

So my question is: how do I properly setup the credentials as env. variables that I can access the files on S3 via gunicorn.

Please note that I only want to pass the gunicorn process the credentials. I do not want to store them in a config. file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know anything about webfaction, but boto will also look for credentials in a boto config file.  By default it will look in `/etc/boto.cfg` and in `~/.boto`.  This file is an INI style config file and you need to add your credentials like this:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = <key ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <key>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I only want to pass the process the credentials. I do not want to store them in a .config file because of security concerns.

Comment: I wonder if you need to edit your Apache configuration file to get it to pick up the AWS_* environment variables and pass them on to the WSGI environment?  It's been a while, but isn't there a SetEnv directive in the httpd.conf file?  If you are not using Apache, I wonder if there is an equivalent.

Comment: I m new to gunicorn (first setup :) and I have no clue about apache. But I solved my problem as it was only a user problem.. I added the environment variables in a different ssh terminal, and started the gunicorn server from another one. Which is not working as you set the env.var. for each terminal only. When I export / set the credentials in the terminal where I m starting gunicorn it is working as expected.